# Yet another get_posts() in explicitly defined order problem

Tags: get-posts, order

I am creating a 'loop' that needs to display *pages* (not posts) in a defined order of ids. What I did till now is:

```
<?php
$ids = array(434, 814, 3660, 3235, 99, 1002, etc.);

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'enforce_specific_order');

function enforce_specific_order($orderby) {
    global $wpdb;
    $ids_as_text = join(",",$ids);
    return "FIND_IN_SET(".$wpdb->posts.".ID, '".$ids_as_text."') ASC";
}

global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => $ids );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php endforeach; remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I can see the pages titles correctly displayed but not in the order I am expecting based on the `$ids`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you should use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Something like so:

```
$specific_order_pages_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in'  => $ids,
    'orderby'   => 'post__in'
);

$specific_order_pages_query = new WP_Query( $specific_order_pages_query_args );
```

WP_Query's order value `post__in` is a special value to order by the supplied `post__in` ID's

See more under Order in WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters